# Create procedure using SELECT sum and JOIN

Tags: sql-server, query

I am using ADO.net with SQL server. I created a stored procedure to get multiple records count. The other queries return the correct results, but the last two queries, which count the total amount of refunds in 1 year and one month are returning incorrect results(NULL). Following is my query.

```
    USE [jobportal]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetAdminReportData]    Script Date: 4/17/2022 5:50:00 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    
    ALTER proc [dbo].[GetAdminReportData]  
    AS  
    
    DECLARE
    @JobseekersCount bigint,
    @ActiveJobseekers bigint,
    @DeactivatedJobseekers bigint,
    @JobseekersLast365Days bigint,
    @JobseekersLast30Days bigint,
    @TotalRefund30Days bigint,
    @TotalRefund365Days bigint

    SELECT @JobseekersCount = count(1) FROM Users u WHERE u.User_Type_ID = 2 and u.is_Active = 1  
    SELECT @ActiveJobseekers = count(1) FROM Users u WHERE u.User_Type_ID = 2 and Status_ID = 1 and u.is_Active = 1  
    SELECT @DeactivatedJobseekers = count(1) FROM Users u WHERE u.User_Type_ID = 2 and Status_ID <> 1 and u.is_Active = 1  
    SELECT @JobseekersLast365Days = count(1) FROM Users u WHERE u.User_Type_ID = 2 and Joining_Date <= getdate() and Joining_Date > getdate() - 365  
    SELECT @JobseekersLast30Days = count(1) FROM Users u WHERE u.User_Type_ID = 2 and Joining_Date <= getdate() and Joining_Date > getdate() - 30
      
      
    SELECT  
    @JobseekersCount as JobseekersCount, @ActiveJobseekers as ActiveJobseekers, @DeactivatedJobseekers as DeactivatedJobseekers, @JobseekersLast365Days as JobseekersLast365Days, @JobseekersLast30Days as JobseekersLast30Days,
    @TotalRefund365Days as TotalRefund365Days, @TotalRefund30Days as TotalRefund30Days


SELECT @TotalRefund30Days = sum(a.total_amount)
 from  [dbo].[UserPurchase] a
       inner join [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds] b 
               on a.user_purchase_id = b.user_purchase_id
 where b.DateCreated >  (getdate() - 30)
 GROUP BY a.is_refunded
 HAVING a.is_refunded = 1

 SELECT @TotalRefund365Days = sum(a.total_amount)
 from  [dbo].[UserPurchase] a
       inner join [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds] b 
               on a.user_purchase_id = b.user_purchase_id
 where a.is_refunded = 1 AND b.DateCreated >  (getdate() - 380)
```

**[dbo].[UserPurchase]**
[image: [dbo].[UserPurchase]]

**[dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds]**
[image: [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds]]

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906399/create-procedure-using-select-join-not-returning-correct-result) in StackOverflow

Comment: Your queries are a little confusing and seem to be doing unnecessary work. Why join to `dbo.UserPurchaseRefunds` when `dbo.UserPurchase` has a field to tell you if it's a refund, called `is_refunded`? Or why even use the `dbo.UserPurchase` table at all when your `dbo.UserPurchaseRefunds` table has an `Amount` column?

Comment: UserpurchaseRefunds also has an Amount column but it shows the amount of how many times this item was purchased not the charges.

Comment: You may want to consider calling that column something else then like `Quantity`, which is a more typical name for that kind of column. That aside, it seems like you don't need to join to `dbo.UserPurchaseRefunds` to achieve your goal?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks for the column name suggestion. But we can't get result of last 30 days or 365 days using only UserPurchase column because the refund dates are in dbo.UserPurchaseRefunds table as DateCreated

Answer (score 1):

You're returning the results before assigning two of the variables.  The SELECT that returns all the variable values to the client should be the last statement in the procedure.

```
SELECT @TotalRefund30Days = sum(a.total_amount)
 from  [dbo].[UserPurchase] a
       inner join [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds] b 
               on a.user_purchase_id = b.user_purchase_id
 where b.DateCreated >  (getdate() - 30)
 GROUP BY a.is_refunded
 HAVING a.is_refunded = 1

 SELECT @TotalRefund365Days = sum(a.total_amount)
 from  [dbo].[UserPurchase] a
       inner join [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds] b 
               on a.user_purchase_id = b.user_purchase_id
 where a.is_refunded = 1 AND b.DateCreated >  (getdate() - 380)

    SELECT  
    @JobseekersCount as JobseekersCount, @ActiveJobseekers as ActiveJobseekers, @DeactivatedJobseekers as DeactivatedJobseekers, @JobseekersLast365Days as JobseekersLast365Days, @JobseekersLast30Days as JobseekersLast30Days,
    @TotalRefund365Days as TotalRefund365Days, @TotalRefund30Days as TotalRefund30Days
```

Comment: Browne. Thanks for the reply but your query is returning the total amount in result not "WHERE a.is_refunded =1"

Comment: Looks like the JOIN to UserPurchaseRefunds is generating duplicates.

Comment: yes. I created the following query. Working fine but is it the correct way?

 SELECT (SELECT sum(a.total_amount) from UserPurchase a WHERE a.is_refunded = 1) AS TotalRefund365Days from [dbo].[UserPurchase] a
 inner join [dbo].[UserPurchaseRefunds] b on a.user_purchase_id=b.user_purchase_id
 where b.DateCreated >  getdate() - 380
 GROUP BY a.is_refunded